# XSLT transformation sample needed

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a not so pretty XSD I am trying to clean. This is what it looks like:-

```
<xs:complexType name="A">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="B">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref='Moniker' maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I want to change definition of element B to the following when maxOccurs for monicker (which is just the name for B) is 1 and B has an attribute "type" with type string and another attribute value with type string.

So final schema should like like so when those conditions are true:-

```
<xs:complexType name="A">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
```

Any ideas on how to do this in XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, start off with the XSLT identity transform to copy elements as-is

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then write out templates for elements you wish to change (XSLT has a concept of template priorities, and will give priority to templates matching specific element names). You've explained the rules for matching, so it should just be a case of translating them into XPATH expressions

```
<xsl:template match="xs:element[@name='B']
   [xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@ref='Moniker']/@maxOccurs='1']
   [xs:complexType/xs:attribute[@name='type']/@type='xs:string']
   [xs:complexType/xs:attribute[@name='value']/@type='xs:string']">
      <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string" />
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you could approach it by writing a template to match the child **complexType** and turning that into an attribute.

```
<xsl:template match="xs:element[@name='B']/xs:complexType
   [xs:sequence/xs:element[@ref='Moniker']/@maxOccurs='1']
   [xs:attribute[@name='type']/@type='xs:string']
   [xs:attribute[@name='value']/@type='xs:string']">
      <xsl:attribute name="type">xs:string</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="xs:element[@name='B']/xs:complexType
      [xs:sequence/xs:element[@ref='Moniker']/@maxOccurs='1']
      [xs:attribute[@name='type']/@type='xs:string']
      [xs:attribute[@name='value']/@type='xs:string']">
      <xsl:attribute name="type">xs:string</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get started!